# Define partial struct with IDA

Tags: ida, struct

I want to define struct in Ida , but I know only partial of this struct

I only know that in `arr[12]` that int student_id , and I don't know the rest of struct. Ida recognize that struct as `char *` .

How can I define that struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
struct partially_known {
  char gap0[12];
  int student_id;
  char gap10[32];
};
```